# Ajax doesn't invoke error function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a backend program written in Java which allows the admin to create new companies to the database. However, the program doesn't allows duplicating companies with the same name so whenever that happens it throws exception.

This is my code for the method, however it always invokes the success function no matter if it failed or succeed.

```
$("#create-company").on('click', function() {
    var company = {
        compName: $compName.val(),
        password: $password.val(),
        email: $email.val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "rest/admin/company",
        data: JSON.stringify(company),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function() {
            alert("Company has been successfully created!");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Error creating company. Please check your input.");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the response from the server when a duplicate is found? The `success` handler will always execute if a `200 OK` response is received.

Comment: Try to insert a duplicated value that isn't allowed on your database directly with a Query, and paste to us the result.

Comment: Do you have any returned value after sending the post request.
You could use  success: function(data) and parse data to check if it is successful